# How to raise Google Reader RSS feed entry limit?

Tags: google-reader, rss

I have a combined RSS feed of all my RSS feeds in Google Reader. The URL is like:
`http://www.google.com/reader/atom/user%F4K3U53RC0D3%2Fstate%2Fcom.google%2Freading-list`. But that feed contains only the last 20 entries, so sometimes if there is more of them, they get lost.

Is there a way (in Google Reader settings or in an URL parameter) that could raise that limit from 20 up to, let's say, 100?

Comment: Are you sure this is a Google Reader limitation? I have plenty of feeds that display more than 20 new items in Google Reader. I suspect it's your RSS aggregator that only sends the latest 20 items.

Comment: I have plenty of feeds that display more than 20 items in Google Reader too. The problem is not with them. The problem is with the feed that Google Reader provides. And that has 20 items only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.google.com/reader/atom/user/-/state/com.google/reading-list?n=3 for 3 items;
the number can be upto 1000.

For the next set of items after that you need to use the continuation parameter found near the beginning of the feed (gr:continuation -> 'c=...' in the URL),
so then in the form of http://www.google.com/reader/atom/user/-/state/com.google/reading-list?c=CL7ygu7h2rAC&n=3

Works for all the provided atom feeds, whether a cached feed, folder/tag, starred or bundle.